# Parameter pass from .bat to .vbs

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have vbs script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RUN "cmd /c r:\iprem.bat" & " " & Wscript.Arguments(0), 0
```

So i run this script and pass some data as argument. Than my bat file process this data. 
I want to pass this processed data back from bat to vbs and of course force vbs script to wait for that data and doesnt stop until it gets it.

have no idea how to do both of these task.

Could anyone help me pls.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? i.e. what is the overall big picture/goal? Maybe what you want is easier in plain VBS :)

Comment: my vbs script is running during logout from windows. my bat script is connecting using ssh with my proxy server. Unfortunately windows is closing connection before ssh finishes. This is because windows finishes vbs script - doesnt wait for bat. I want to force it to wait for some kind of confirmation from bat .

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on what the batch file does with the processed data. If it prints the data to STDOUT you could the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead of `Run` and read the output from `StdOut` after the batch file is finished.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set iprem = sh.Exec("cmd /c r:\iprem.bat " & Wscript.Arguments(0))

Do While iprem.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

result = iprem.StdOut.ReadAll
```

This will briefly show a CMD window, though, since the `Exec` method doesn't allow for running hidden processes. If you want to avoid that you have to stick with the `Run` method and redirect the output to a temporary file, e.g. like this:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outfile = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%\tempfile.txt")

sh.Run "cmd /c r:\iprem.bat " & Wscript.Arguments(0) & " >" & outfile, 0, True

result = fso.OpenTextFile(outfile).ReadAll

fso.DeleteFile outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your .bat file so it has this line first:

```
cscript C:\YourScript.vbs

REM Do any other batch file processing here.
```

So, instead of running .bat from .vbs you are running .vbs from .bat.